# Monte Carlo Method to evaluate sum

Tags: sequences-and-series, random-variables, law-of-large-numbers, monte-carlo

I want to approximate the sum

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{\lambda^k}{k!}b_k$$

where $b_k, k \in \mathbb{N}_0$ is a bounded sequence. I was thinking about constructing a independent random variables $X_i$ with $\mathbb{E}[X_i] = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{\lambda^k}{k!}b_k$ and then using the weak law of large numbers. I'm stuck at this point and don't know how to start the construction.

Comment: $\sum_{k=0}^N \frac{\lambda^k}{k!}b_k$.

Comment: $\newcommand{\E}{\Bbb{E}}$One possibility is to note that your sum is $e^\lambda \E [b_Z]$, where $Z\sim \mathsf{Poisson}(\lambda)$.

Comment: @MinusOne-Twelfth Thank you. I see it now!